# How to set default value in parameter object property

Tags: flowtype

coming from [1](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1081)

Is it possible to set a default value here?

```
const Header = (props:  {
  isAdmin: boolean = false,
  dispatch: Function
}) =>  (
  <Toolbar style={style.bar}>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is not support for the feature yet

[Add support for destructuring parameters + default values](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/183)

For now I am doing

```
const Header = ({isAdmin , dispatch}: {
  isAdmin: boolean;
  dispatch: Function
}) => (
  <Toolbar style={style.bar}>
...

Header.defaultProps = {
  isAdmin: false
}
```

Comment: Default values in destructuring declarations were recently added to Flow, are in `master` now and will be in the next release.